# Error in parsing json data

Tags: java, android, json

I have this json data.I want to parse it.I am getting error when I am trying to do

```
JsonObject json=new JsonObject(x);
```

Because it contains white spaces.

```
{id=11, note=A sample note,}
```

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your example a valid JSON wrap the properties and values in double quotes, remove the last comma and replace your equal sign with colon.

The result will look like this:

```
{
    "id": "11",
    "note": "A sample note"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to keep in mind two things:

**1) Check If The JSON Format Is Right:**

The JSON Format Of your Data Should Be like [This](http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/).

**2) Check That Your Code is Correct:**

Visit This [Website](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) for Code.